# Python path not finding text file

Tags: python, cloud-foundry, pythonpath

I have my python code in this structure:

```
folder:
   Procfile
   folder2:
      myprog.py
      foo.py
      somefile.txt
```

My `Procfile` contains `web: python folder2/myprog.py`

`myprog.py` contains:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
#other code
```

`foo.py` contains:

```
print "about to read file"
file = open("somefile.txt", "r") 
print file.read() 
print "done reading"
```

I'm not able to read the file. The code never reached `done reading` part eventhough it prints `about to read file`

Comment: Does it throw an error? The `sys.path.insert('..')` is a trick for adding module path searches (`import  xyz`)`, not for opening normal files.

Comment: After surrounding it with `try/catch` I get this error `I/O error(2): No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't think it tries to open the file where you think it tries to open it. try `print os.getcwd()` (and make sure you have a line `import os`) before that) to see in which directory you are. My guess is you need to do `file = open("folder2/somefile.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the automatic module variable `__file__` and the fact that you know `somefile.txt` is in the same directory as `foo.py`:

```
file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "somefile.txt"), "r")
```

`sys.path` only determines the search path for importing modules, not where generic files will be opened from the filesystem.

Comment: Another slight variation would be `file = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'folder2', 'somefile.txt'), 'r')`.  `os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory which on Cloud Foundry will be the root of your project (unless you were to specifically change this in your Procfile).